# Please let me know if I can provide any further information

Tags: writing

I have read multiple emails ended up with this sentence:

```
Please let me know if I can provide any further information!
```

Is this sentence appropriate in an email? For example: 
Let's say that an employer is inquiring, by email, about some issues from an employee. The employee responded to the employer questions, then ended up his email saying "Please let me know if I can provide any further information!".

Here, given that the employer will, definitely, not feeling shy from the employee to ask again and again about some other issues. Is the usage of this sentence is appropriate, or it is a formal way to show politeness in an email.